# How to process fields between matching patterns?

Tags: awk

Related post: [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

@fedorqui, thanks for providing all these different options for awk. I have been using this to parse through var log messages when troubleshooting ooms and it works great. I want to extend this further but I have not been able to figure out how to proceed. What I am trying to do:

1. Print the lines between rss and out of memory. I have done that with the example
2. Order the sections between each match by rss field. I have not been able to figure this out
3. Add an extra column with its own header and perform some mathematical operation. I have been able to do this somewhat but I am running into some formatting issues. I am not sure how to skip the first and last line when adding the column so I lose those lines. I am also not able to keep the spacing from the original if I do any operations other than print.

Here's the command I am using right now:

```
less /var/log/messages'|awk '/swapents/{x=1; print "=================="};/Out of memory/{x=0} x'|sed 's/[]\[]//g'
```

Here's the source Data:

```
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.617265  pid    uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.622250  1828     0  1828     4331      116      14       3        0         -1000 udevd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.627310  2664     0  2664    28002       53      23       3        0         -1000 auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.633181  2680     0  2680    62032     1181      24       4        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.638888  2694     0  2694     3444       61      11       3        0             0 irqbalance
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.644912  2710    81  2710     5430       56      14       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.651108  2779     0  2779    19958      203      42       3        0         -1000 sshd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.656670  2789     0  2789     5622       56      17       3        0             0 xinetd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.653452  Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
blah
blah
blah
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.617265  pid    uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.622250  1828     0  1828     4331      116      14       3        0         -1000 udevd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.627310  2664     0  2664    28002       53      23       3        0         -1000 auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.633181  2680     0  2680    62032     1181      24       4        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.638888  2694     0  2694     3444       61      11       3        0             0 irqbalance
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.644912  2710    81  2710     5430       56      14       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.651108  2779     0  2779    19958      203      42       3        0         -1000 sshd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.656670  2789     0  2789     5622       56      17       3        0             0 xinetd
Sep  8 11:35:15 ip-10-23-15-70 kernel: 11810061.653452  Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
```

Here's what my output looks like:

```
==================      0MB
Sep 8 11:35:15 pid  0MB name         <---- should be header (Pid virt rss etc)
Sep 8 11:35:15 1828 0MB udevd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2664 0MB auditd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2680 4MB rsyslogd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2694 0MB irqbalance
Sep 8 11:35:15 2710 0MB dbus-daemon
Sep 8 11:35:15 2779 0MB sshd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2789 0MB xinetd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2822 0MB crond
Sep 8 11:35:15 Out  0MB or           <---- should be footer (out of memory etc)
==================      0MB 
Sep 8 11:35:15 pid  0MB name         <---- should be header (Pid virt rss etc)
Sep 8 11:35:15 1828 0MB udevd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2664 0MB auditd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2680 4MB rsyslogd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2694 0MB irqbalance
Sep 8 11:35:15 2710 0MB dbus-daemon
Sep 8 11:35:15 2779 0MB sshd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2789 0MB xinetd
Sep 8 11:35:15 2822 0MB crond
Sep 8 11:35:15 Out  0MB or           <---- should be footer (out of memory etc)
==================      0MB
```

You can see the from the output that the separator I added for each oom field, awk tries to calculate values for it, I would love to avoid this if possible. Also the header and footer are getting chopped off and it would be nice to avoid that too.

Here's what I would like:

```
========================
Sep  8 11:35:15   pid   rss  memused_MB      oom_score_adj name
Sep  8 11:35:15   2664   53  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2789   56  {rss*4/1024}                0 xinetd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2710   56  {rss*4/1024}                0 dbus-dae
Sep  8 11:35:15   2694   61  {rss*4/1024}                0 irqbalan
Sep  8 11:35:15   1828  116  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 udevd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2680  181  {rss*4/1024}                0 rsyslogd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2779  203  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 sshd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
========================
Sep  8 11:35:15   pid   rss  memused_MB      oom_score_adj name
Sep  8 11:35:15   2664   53  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2789   56  {rss*4/1024}                0 xinetd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2710   56  {rss*4/1024}                0 dbus-dae
Sep  8 11:35:15   2694   61  {rss*4/1024}                0 irqbalan
Sep  8 11:35:15   1828  116  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 udevd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2680  181  {rss*4/1024}                0 rsyslogd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   2779  203  {rss*4/1024}            -1000 sshd 
Sep  8 11:35:15   Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
========================
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/swapents/ {
   x=1;
   print "=================="
   printf( "%s  %s %s   pid\t%4s\tmemused_MB\toom_score_adj\tname\n", $1, $2, $3, "rss");
   next
}
/Out of memory/ {
   printf( "%s  %s %s   %s\n", $1, $2, $3, substr($0,index($0,$7)));
   x=0
}
x {
   printf( "%s  %s %s   %s\t%4d\t%10.5f\t%13d\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $7, $11, ($11*4)/1024, $15, $16 )
}
```

You can play around with the formatting, like the precision in column 6, using the specifiers in the printf function. Call this with:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk /var/log/messages
```

> EDIT: **with sorting**

OP asked to sort the output by rss columns. Using a standard `sort` wouldn't work here because you want to sort in between starting and ending matches. You can solve this by saving the intermediate result in an array and sort that with a self-defined function. Like this:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
/swapents/ {
    x=1;
    print "=================="
    printf( "%s  %s %s   pid\t%4s\tmemused_MB\toom_score_adj\tname\n", $1, $2, $3, "rss");
    next
}
/Out of memory/ {
    n=asort(a, sorted, "cmp_rss")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print sorted[i]
    }
    delete a;
    printf( "%s  %s %s   %s\n", $1, $2, $3, substr($0,index($0,$7)));
    x=0
}
x {
    a[i++] = sprintf( "%s  %s %s   %s\t%4d\t%10.5f\t%13d\t%s", $1, $2, $3, $7, $11, ($11*4)/1024, $15, $16 );
}
function cmp_rss(i1, v1, i2, v2)
{
    split(v1, a1, " ")
    split(v2, a2, " ")
    rss1=a1[5];
    rss2=a2[5];
    return (rss1 - rss2)
}
```

which leads to:

```
$ awk -f tst2.awk input.txt
==================
Sep  8 11:35:15   pid    rss    memused_MB  oom_score_adj   name
Sep  8 11:35:15   2664    53       0.20703          -1000   auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2710    56       0.21875              0   dbus-daemon
Sep  8 11:35:15   2789    56       0.21875              0   xinetd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2694    61       0.23828              0   irqbalance
Sep  8 11:35:15   1828   116       0.45312          -1000   udevd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2779   203       0.79297          -1000   sshd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2680  1181       4.61328              0   rsyslogd
Sep  8 11:35:15   Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
==================
Sep  8 11:35:15   pid    rss    memused_MB  oom_score_adj   name
Sep  8 11:35:15   2664    53       0.20703          -1000   auditd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2710    56       0.21875              0   dbus-daemon
Sep  8 11:35:15   2789    56       0.21875              0   xinetd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2694    61       0.23828              0   irqbalance
Sep  8 11:35:15   1828   116       0.45312          -1000   udevd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2779   203       0.79297          -1000   sshd
Sep  8 11:35:15   2680  1181       4.61328              0   rsyslogd
Sep  8 11:35:15   Out of memory: Kill process 43390 (mysql) score 1000 or sacrifice child
```

Comment: hey awesome solution. This is what I used.

/swapents/ {
   x=1;
   print "=================="
   gsub(/\[|\]/, "")
   print $0"\t\t"$11
   next
}
{gsub(/\[|\]/, "")}
/Out of memory/ {
     print $0
     x=0
}
x {printf "%s\t\t %10.2f\n", $0,$11*4/1024}

This does not sort though. Is there a way to use this on command line without creating a file? I can't create files on the machine am using.

Comment: Added sorting example of rss column. Not creating a file? Sure, just `awk -f tst2.awk input.txt` doesn't create a file for you.

Comment: Thanks for the sort method, thats pretty cool. By not creating a file, I meant I can't create the awk file on the machine I will be running this on. Looks like I may have to do the sorting externally :( . Thanks for the help, this will do for now, will live without sorting.

Comment: I can imagine you're not allowed access to a corporate production server. However, some companies use logservers where they allow read-access. And: there's no obligation, but you could accept the answer if you're really happy with it.

Comment: yeah that is true but log servers only have logs from 2days before. So i would have to wait which doesn't work too well since the issue is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marc Lambrichs response I was able to create this one liner that does the job. Thanks so much. The only thing missing now is sorting by the rss column, I haven't been able to get the rss field sorted though

```
less /var/log/messages|awk '/swapents/ {x=1; print "==================";gsub(/\[|\]/, "") ;printf "%s %s %s %s %10s %10s %10s %15s memory_used %-s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10,$11,$15,$16 ;next } {gsub(/\[|\]/, "")} /Out of memory/ {print $0 ;x=0 } x {printf "%s %s %s %s %10s %10s %10s %15s %9.2fMB %-s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10,$11,$15,$11*4/1024,$16}'
```

For readability, the awk code formatted:

```
/swapents/ {
    x=1; 
    print "==================";
    gsub(/\[|\]/, "");
    printf "%s %s %s %s %10s %10s %10s %15s memory_used %-s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10,$11,$15,$16 ;
    next 
} 
{
    gsub(/\[|\]/, "")
} 
/Out of memory/ {
    print $0;
    x=0 
} 
x {
    printf "%s %s %s %s %10s %10s %10s %15s %9.2fMB %-s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10,$11,$15,$11*4/1024,$16
}
```

Comment: Added sorting example to my answer.